# Rails 4, ActiveRecord, find all posts that are not commented by current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise, find, where-clause

As the title suggests, looking for the right ActiveRecord syntax to find all posts where the Devise current_user has not left a comment in... I tried searching for similar, but couldn't find anything. Note the subtle request - i'm NOT looking for all posts with no comments, but rather looking for all posts where the current_user hasn't posted a comment. Hoping someone can help!

Post has_many Comments, and Comment belongs_to Post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone else have any ideas? would want to see other options. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an information about which posts have been commented by the user so you have to basically just search for the "others" posts.

```
class User
  has_many :comments
end

class Post
  has_many :comments

  scope :not_commented_by, ->(user) { 
    where.not(id: user.comments.select('post_id as id'))
  }
end

# in a controller
def index
  @posts = Post.not_commented_by(current_user)
end
```

Comment: getting a syntax error in the Post model - at (user) ->

Comment: hmm still seeing the error. its highlighting the space between -> and {

Comment: fixed. try it one more time. sorry, it's late for me.